# tabris - rap-1.5.target runtime load issue

Tags: eclipse, mobile

Whenever I try to use this rap-1.5.target file which has http://developer.eclipsesource.com/technology/tabris/downloads/0.6 as a repository location I get the following errors in Eclipse. 
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature, com.eclipsesource.tabris.feature,0.6.2.v20120801-0412
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle, com.eclipsesource.tabris,0.6.2.v20120801-0412
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature, org.eclipsesource.tabris.source,0.6.2.v20120801-0412
session context was:(profile=TARGET_DEFINITION:resource/com.eclipsesource.tabris.demos/rap-1.5.target, phase=org.eclipse.equiniox.internal.p2.engibe.phases.Collect, operand=,action=).

Answer (score 2):

This is because the tabris target location is a composite p2 repository which keeps only the 10 last entries. A simple solution is to open the target file, click the tabris repository and  press update on the right. After this you have to save and set the target platform.